# How to delete a broken symbolic file link in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8, symbolic-link

So I have a file in a directory with an unicode name. I wanted to create a link to this elsewhere, but when I tried to do it with a command like `mklink file "S:\ディレクトリ\target"` in cmd.exe, the result was a broken symlink (the unicode characters showed up as boxes in the command). Running `attrib` on the links just says "The target of the symbolic link file does not exist", so it certainly seems broken for good.

And now the really annoying part about this: I can't delete the damn thing. Trying to do it in Explorer just tells me I can't, trying to use `del` from an elevated prompt just gives me "Access is denied." Trying to overwrite the symlink with a new (working) one doesn't work either, just gives me "Cannot create a file when that file already exists."

So, how could I go about deleting this? And as a bonus question, any ideas on how to get symbolic links for unicode paths working?

Comment: maybe the `rd` command can help you - https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how

You need to insert the command: `chcp 65001`

"which will change the code page to UTF-8. Also, you need to use Lucida console fonts."

Also note: "Note there are serious implementation bugs in Windows's code page 65001 support which will break many applications that rely on the C standard library IO methods, so this is very fragile. (Batch files also just stop working in 65001.) Unfortunately UTF-8 is a second-class citizen in Windows"

Comment: Sounds quite fragile indeed. Guess I'll just rename the directories or  move the files I want to link instead. Still need a solution for the main issue of getting rid of the broken symlinks, though.